# Confused about SharePoint Solutions

Tags: 2010, sandbox-solution, solution-deployment, farm-solution

I'm confused about SharePoint Solutions. Could you verify if my understanding is correct?

There are [only 2 kinds of SharePoint Solutions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704543%28v=office.14%29.aspx#understanding_solutions):

1. **Sandboxed Solutions**: When a solution package is deployed to the solution store of a site collection, it is called a 'sandboxed solution'. ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543214.aspx#Anchor_1))
2. **Farm Solutions**: When a solution package is deployed to the farm's solution store, it is called a 'farm solution'. ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543214.aspx#Anchor_1))

Creating a Site Template always saves the site as a Sandboxed Solution (.wsp). Installing a Sandboxed Solution can be done using PowerShell commands:

1. [Add-SPUserSolution](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607715%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
2. [Install-SPUserSolution](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607653%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

A requirement to adding and installing the Site Template Solution (= Sandboxed Solution) requires the SharePoint Service "SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service" (SPUserCodeV4) to be active on at least 1 server.

It is not possible to add and activate the Site Template Solution without the Sandboxed Code Service being active on at least one server in the farm.

When a Sandboxed Solution is added, it can be found in the Site Collection Solution Gallery.

Questions being:

- Are there only 2 kinds of SharePoint Solutions?
- Does the SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service" (SPUserCodeV4) have to be active on at least one server in order to add and activate a sandboxed solution?
- On what server(s) should the SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service" (SPUserCodeV4) be active?
- Creating a Site Template using "[Save Site as Template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template-5a4eb024-d1fa-4681-a4ac-e6bd1e3209ba)" always creates a Sandboxed Solution (.wsp). Never a Farm Solution.
- Is there a way for me to see what kind of solution I am dealing with based on the .wsp file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there only 2 kinds of SharePoint Solutions?

yes, but since SP 2013 we could count the APPs as a separate solution type as well

> Does the SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service" (SPUserCodeV4)
>   have to be active ...

yes

> On what server(s) should...Code Service" (SPUserCodeV4) be active?

I would suggest on the front end

> "Save Site as Template" always creates a Sandboxed Solution...

it creates a site template in solution store, that's right, but you could use this template in a farm solution as well. So I would say in this case the container where site templates and sandbox solutions are stored in is the same.

> way for me to see what kind of solution

one possible way to detect farm solutions:

1. make a copy of the wsp file and rename its ending to "cab"
2. open the cab file (usually by Windows Explorer - cab files are like zip archives)
3. search for manifest.xml and open it
4. if you find `DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache"` it's definitely a farm solution

Comment: If I have 2 Web Servers, should I enable the SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service (SPUserCodeV4) on both servers, or only on 1? Or should this be [activated on the Application Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff535775%28v=office.14%29.aspx)?

Comment: quoted from technet.microsoft.com:  "Enable sandboxed solutions on every application server on which you want to run sandboxed solutions."